# Algoritmo em Java, aumentar idade;

Tags: java, algoritmo

Queria saber como fazer um algoritmo em que eu inserisse um ano, e o valor incrementasse com a idade, como ano 2016=1, ano 2017 = 2, em um método.

Algo como isso:

```
int fazAniversidade(int ano) {
    if(ano == 2015) {
        this.idade +=1;
    }
    if(ano == 2016) {
        this.idade +=2;
    }

    return 0;

 }
```

Mas em um loop, como fazer?

Comment: Qual regra você vai usar pra incrementar o ano? Vai fazer a leitura do tempo no sistema ou é só um teste?

Comment: acho que você poderia por mais detalhes, tentar esclarecer melhor sua dúvida.

Answer (score 6):

1. Não faz sentido retornar `0` (zero) se a intenção é somente setar `this.idade = x`. Neste caso, use `void` na função.
2. Não é preciso utilizar `loop`, basta pegar a diferença entre o ano atual e o ano informado na chamada da função.

**Resultado**

**`Main.java`**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main
{

    static int idade;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        idade = 10;
        fazAniversidade(2015); // seta idade = 11
        //fazAniversidade(2016); // seta idade = 12
        //fazAniversidade(2017); // seta idade = 13
    }

    public static void fazAniversidade(int ano)
    {
        int ano_atual = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int diferenca = (ano - ano_atual) + 1;

        idade += diferenca;
    }
}
```